# Is there a way to do MPI_Gatherv without knowing the size of each array in each process?

Tags: c++, mpi

I'm trying to do MPI_Gatherv for array of int without knowing the size of each array in each processes. Is there a way to do it?

Here is snippet of my code.

```
#include "mpi.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    int *local_arr;
    int *arr;
    int local_n;
    int n;

    if (rank == 0) {

        // do gatherv without knowing the element sizes and displacements

    } else {
        // fill array with random size
        srand(rank);
        local_n = (rand()%10)+1;
        local_arr = new int[local_n];

        for (int i = 0; i < local_n; i++) {
            local_arr[i] = i;
        }

        // do gatherv without knowing the element sizes and displacements
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide a MCVE of what you have so far https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. This way people can quickly copy your example, compile it on their machines, and add/correct the missing lines in it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot really do that. The presence of the `displacements` and `element_sizes` arguments suggest that. If there really is no way of knowing (no way of calculating at root) the counts that root will receive, you will need to do a `MPI_Gather` of a single `int` from each node and use that as `displacements` in `MPI_Gatherv`.

Comment: If you are not calling `MPI_Gatherv` too often, this should be no problem. If you are then either think of how to calculate the element counts at root, or at least keep them constant so that you will only need one call of `MPI_Gather`.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a call to `Gatherv`, you have to know the sizes and displacements beforehand, because you simply need to allocate sufficient space on the target rank.

That's why you will often see a `Gather` call before to get each rank's size, then a reduction to get the displacements and then the `Gatherv` call. If there are several of the latter with fixed sizes on the different ranks, then the `Gather` would be called in a preprocessing step.

Comment: oh i see then.. Thank you :)